# Strange behaviour in replace() in Python

Tags: python, string

I can't figure out with this issue...

I have these few lines of code that have a strange behaviour:

```
print("1...")

for x in range(n_vocaboli):
    vocabolo_de = vocaboli_de[x].get_text().replace("\n", "")
    print(vocabolo_de)
    csv_raw = csv_raw + vocabolo_de

print("2...")

print(csv_raw)
```

I have a list of german words in "vocaboli_de" that I extract with a for loop, putting it in the "vocabolo_de" variable. When I print it (1), all goes fine, but... when I add it (2) to "csv_raw", it doesn't work!

(1) output

```
1...
der Anker, -
der Amboss, e
die Klinge, n
das Brett, er
[...]
die Schubkarre, n
der Draht, "e
der Holzspan, "e
der Schraubenschlüssel, -
```

(2) output

```
2...
der Schraubenschlüssel, -
```

I guess this is a stupid mistake, but I can't really find it... :(

Comment: Try adding `.replace("\r", "")` as well.

Comment: Oh, thank you! Now it works! <3

Comment: Using `strip()` would cover both and other whitespace.